# Accessing GoogleApiClient object in All Activities

Tags: android, singleton, google-plus

This seems like a simple thing that most people would need if they wanted to use Google Plus sign in with their application :s.

In Activity 1:

I sign the user in.

After the sign in, I want to make that user object globally accessible, so I add it to the Application object:

```
public class GlobalUserAccess extends Application {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    public GlobalUserAccess(){
        mGoogleApiClient = null;
    }

    public void setClient(GoogleApiClient client){
        mGoogleApiClient = client;
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getClient(){
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }
}
```

By binding it like so:

```
GlobalUserAccess client = ((GlobalUserAccess) getApplicationContext());
client.setClient(mGoogleApiClient);
```

However, when I try to access it in Activity 2:

```
GlobalUserAccess client = ((GlobalUserAccess) getApplicationContext());
String currentUser = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(client.getClient());
```

I get the error:

```
E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
```

Can someone please fill me in on the proper way to accomplish this? I'd like to have that user object available to all classes and I've spent way too much time on this :|.

Did I mess up somewhere? Ah...

EDIT: client creation code from Activity 1

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
        .build();
```

I'm using Googles code directly from their Git repository. It successfully signs in and gets the account info in Activity 1.

Comment: how you created mGoogleApiClient post its code.

Comment: Done! I edited my post.

Comment: Is it possible to access GoogleApiClient in a class which is not a component of Android ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add google play location services dependency and location permission in manifest file

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'
```

**GoogleApiHelper.java**

```
public class GoogleApiHelper implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
        private static final String TAG = GoogleApiHelper.class.getSimpleName();
        private Context context;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private ConnectionListener connectionListener;
        private Bundle connectionBundle;

        public GoogleApiHelper(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            connect();
        }

        public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
            return this.mGoogleApiClient;
        }

        public void setConnectionListener(ConnectionListener connectionListener) {
            this.connectionListener = connectionListener;
            if (this.connectionListener != null && isConnected()) {
                connectionListener.onConnected(connectionBundle);
            }
        }

        public void connect() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

        public void disconnect() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        public boolean isConnected() {
            return mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();
        }

        private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            connectionBundle = bundle;
            if (connectionListener != null) {
                connectionListener.onConnected(bundle);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: googleApiClient.connect()");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            if (connectionListener != null) {
                connectionListener.onConnectionSuspended(i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: connectionResult = " + connectionResult);
            if (connectionListener != null) {
                connectionListener.onConnectionFailed(connectionResult);
            }
        }

        public interface ConnectionListener {
            void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult);

            void onConnectionSuspended(int i);

            void onConnected(Bundle bundle);
        }
    }
```

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {
    private GoogleApiHelper googleApiHelper;
    private static App mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;
        googleApiHelper = new GoogleApiHelper(mInstance);
    }

    public static synchronized App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public GoogleApiHelper getGoogleApiHelperInstance() {
        return this.googleApiHelper;
    }
    public static GoogleApiHelper getGoogleApiHelper() {
        return getInstance().getGoogleApiHelperInstance();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to specifying the fully-qualified name of this subclass as the "android:name" attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag.

You can get apiClient by callback and get when it will connect

```
App.getGoogleApiHelper().setConnectionListener(new GoogleApiHelper.ConnectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
                //this function will call whenever google api connected or already connected when setting listener
                //You are connected do what ever you want
                //Like i get last known location
                Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            }
        });
```

Or you can also get it like this

```
if(App.getGoogleApiHelper().isConnected())
{
    //Get google api client from anywhere
    GoogleApiClient client = App.getGoogleApiHelper().getGoogleApiClient();
}
```

Comment: The class defined above won't pass compiling. There are a bunch of missing variables and errors (eg. No variable named context, location etc defined anywhere)

Comment: Passing the context from Application class would solve the compilation problem.

Comment: @Codevalley that was incomplete and not compatible with Android N i will try to make it complete and perfect. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() always returns false. How to know if the user is already signed in?

Comment: Once the activity (whose context is used) finishes, isConnected returns false. And then this singleton is really not of much use. Am I missing something here?

Comment: does it automatically closes the client when the application stops ? @Sabeeh

Answer (score 4):

For accessing object from every where, you can do like i did here
[App.java](https://github.com/itboy87/SUH-Tracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/suh/itboy/tracker/App.java). Don't forget to add app in manifest like that

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
```

now to access object simply do that from any where

```
App.getGoogleApiHelper();
```

Also checkout my GoogleApiHelper class here [GoogleApiHelper.java](https://github.com/itboy87/SUH-Tracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/suh/itboy/tracker/Helper/GoogleApi/GoogleApiHelper.java)

For GooglePlus Api check out this [GooglePlusAPI](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating). Follow these steps.

App Code according to your code

```
public class App extends Application {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static App mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public void setClient(GoogleApiClient client){
        mGoogleApiClient = client;
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getClient(){
       return mGoogleApiClient;
    }
}
```

now to initialize and access

```
App.getInstance().setClient(client);
GoogleApiClient client = App.getInstance().getClient();
```

Comment: This works (sort of). I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.` though. Do I need to constantly connect the client in the Application class? (it is 100% connected in Activity 1)

Comment: @Kris you must implement `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and  `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` where you created client and set callbacks checkout my `GoogleApiHelper` Class you can connect GoogleApiClient there like i did

Comment: @Kris when client connect then `onConnected` function is called do there what you need like accessing location or other google services

Comment: I shall try to piece this together! I have all of that implemented in Activity 1, but I feel like there's some stuff that needs to be added to the Application class.

Comment: make sure GoogleApiClient connected before accessing its client

Comment: Should I pull off the connection code out of the Activity and put it into the Application class?

Comment: No wait i will post full example

Answer (score 0):

In your activity 1 when you are trying to get Application object you should do as below:

```
GlobalUserAccess client = ((GlobalUserAccess) getApplication());
```

And then set `GoogleApiClient` object using `setClient` method. In your activity2 use same way to get Application object.