# Limitation of GoogleApiClient in Android

Tags: android, google-signin, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

Unlike facebook login for android, I find GoogleApiClient for android having some limitations.

I am using GoogleApiClient in the following way:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestProfile()
        .build();

// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
// options specified by gso.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

Later in my `onConnected` callback,

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    launchNextActivity();
}
```

1. Why does google have to limit the scope of GoogleApiClient only to one activity? Can't I have a single instance of GoogleApiClient as authentication identifier across my app?
2. How do I signout from another activity? As soon as I leave the login activity, the GoogleApiClient instance is disconnected. (This does not allow me the use the instance of mGoogleApiClient by saving in global scope)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a GoogleApi-Singleton.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400346/570168).

Comment: I have seen that. Even that singleton is limited to context. Please check buildGoogleApiClient() method. So, once we leave the activity (call finish), context is no more valid, mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() returns false again. Do let me know if I'm missing something.